# How can I prevent spammers from following me on Pinterest?

Tags: spam-prevention, pinterest

I have a Pinterest account, which I mainly use to save personal bookmarks. I do not want to share any of my boards, in fact they are all marked as "secret".
Still, every day, I get 5-10 new spam accounts to follow "all of my boards". They are clearly fake accounts from the same "spam pool", each one with the same caption, "tons of girls are waiting for you at bla bla bla".
I reported 30-40 of them, hoping to exhaust their "fake pool", but then I gave up.

Is there a way to block ALL followers? I simply want to share nothing!

Also, a little rant: how can Pinterest's spam filters be so poor as of 2019? It feels like being on a porn site...